# C# - How to disable buttons after number of entries reached

Tags: c#

I am creating a project for school and I have been tasked with the following when creating a button on my form that will Add marks into a simple array:

*"The button (Add) should become disabled after the maximum number of quizzes has been added."*

So far I have figured out that I need to code:
**`btn.Add.Enabled = false`**

*ex.code below*

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{ 
  btn.Add.Enabled = false
}
```

However, I don't know where I should be declaring it along with the rest of the code that will store the quiz marks from the text box on the form.

Should this be part of the `for loop`? Can I declare it on it's own within the BtnAdd Click event?

(thanks in advance from the extreme C# newbie)

Comment: Where do u evaluate `maximum number of quizzes` just make a if condition there itself that if `maximum number of quizzes >= whatever number` than `btn.Add.Enabled = false;`

Comment: I'm sure `btn.Add.Enabled = false;` should be `btnAdd.Enabled = false;` instead. btnAdd is the actual ID of the button.

Comment: Did you not learn the `if` statement in school ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
List<Quiz> quizzes = new List<Quiz>();
int limit = 5;
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var isEnabled = (quizzes.Count < limit);
    If (isEnabled) { quizzes.Add(new Quiz("abc")); } 
    isEnabled = (quizzes.Count < limit);
    btn.Add.Enabled = isEnabled;

}
```

Edited. Streamlined a bit

Comment: I guess, it's better if quiz is added first and then check count. In this case button needs to be clicked to make it disable.

Comment: I would include another quiz count check in the else statement to disable the button as soon as the limit is reached when the button is pressed. This is more for user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an integer variable at the class level (outside of the btnAdd_Click method), name it counter and initialize it to zero.

Inside btnAdd_Click, write an if statement that checks if counter has reached the maximum number of clicks, if it has then disable the button, else increment the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized logic

```
   List<Quiz> lstQuiz = new List<Quiz>();
    int limit = 5;
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Enabled = (lstQuiz.Count >= limit)?false:true;
        lstQuiz.Add(new Quiz());
    }
```